# Draw polylines which follow the roads gemoetry

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-polyline

In my app I want to highlight certain roads, which can easily be achieved just by drawing polylines on top of the roads. (I am using the Google Maps SDK, by the way). However these polylines won't follow the road's geometry, they will just connect two coordinates with a straight line. (I have a coordinate for the start of the road which I want to highlight and the end of it). The coordinates won't change, the same roads will be highlighted through out the whole time in the app.

**The question is:** Is there a way I could draw these polylines not to be straight but to follow the road's geometry? If it's not possible in the SDK, is there a tool on the internet which will connect two coordinates following the roads between them? Because if there is, than I could get the coordinates of those poylines and parse them in my app.

Cheers!

Comment: I am unsure about the Google maps sdk, but I can achieve this in the Apple maps sdk by requesting a route between those points. The route has a polyline that follows roards.

Comment: Oh wow, that sounds pretty cool. But I am looking for a way which does not involve sending route requests as the app would need to work in offline mode.

Comment: You asked whether there was a tool on the internet to connect two coordinates. If it needs to work offline, it won't work unless you're linking a known set of coordinates. If you do have a small set, you could get directions and cache the polylines. If you're trying to work in arbitrary areas while offline, you're going to have a bad time when map tiles aren't loaded. I don't think Google or Apple are likely to expose the map tile (road network) data. You might try MapBox: https://www.mapbox.com/mobile/ You might be able to figure out how to extract road paths on the fly by reading the source.

Comment: It would be perfetcly fine to have a text file with the coordinates loaded into the app because those coordinates would not ever change. The problem is: I don't know where to get those coordinates from. You are suggesting MapKit?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Google's API, but it's probably very similar to Apple's. In your development process (not necessarily in your running app), request a route from either service between points and save the returned polyline to a file.

Answer (score 2):

as @Fabian has suggested, if you have a small set of polylines to show in your app, and your app works mostly offline, it would be better to get all the polylines during the development. And there are two ways:

1) through the [direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro), you might able to skip all the implementation by using the WEB API, which is meant for webserver. 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&avoid=highways&mode=bicycling&key=API_KEY`

2) or, with the [Snap to Road API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo), which might gives you a better control over your route compare to the direction API. This API is meant to fix the pool GPS data you get from the sensor and snap those on the road.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I could extract the  coordinates from the Snap to Road API so I could than draw the polylines along the roads in my app?

Comment: I think the (javascript sample)[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap#demo] shows how to create a polyline from the Snap to Road API in the drawSnappedPolyline() function. you might able to refer to that. (use that code)